# Как правильно: жен./женск.?

Tags: орфография, сокращения, лексикография

Я как знаю, сокращения можно делать, только ставя точку перед последней согласной. Ещё я знаю, что на **ь** или **ъ** нельзя оканчивать сокращения.
Почему тогда есть сокращение *муж.* и *жен.*?
Правильно же было бы *мужск.* и *женск.*, не так ли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Правило](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/140-sokr):

> При стечении двух различных или нескольких согласных сокращение следует делать после последней согласной, например: *народн. творчество* (а не «народ.»), *русск. язык* (а не «рус.»), *искусств. шелк* (а не «искус.», или «искусс.», или «искусст.»).

Правильное (обычное) сокращение такое:
женский — *женск.*, конский — *конск.*;
мужской — *мужск.*, морской — *морск.*

Особенные формы сокращения используются в словарях и в школьных разборах (с целью экономии места и времени):
***ж.*** и ***жен.*** — женский, ***м.*** и ***муж.*** — мужской.

Такие сокращения рекомендованы "не только для словарей и библиографических пособий, но и для самых разных справочных и иных изданий деловой литературы для подготовленного читателя".

[Список сокращений](https://popravilam.com/blog/sokrashcheniya-osnovnye.html#zh) (приложение к «Русскому орфографическому словарю»)

Comment: Сокращения от лукавого вообще-то... Это я всем, риторическое наблюдение.)) Если так можно выразиться)))))

Comment: Две буквы нормально недописывать? Не думаю...

Comment: Артём, это такая же ситуация, как с падежами: ***т., тв., твор.*** (творительный), ***д., дат.*** (дательный) — при особом употреблении. Или с городом — г., или с веком — в., или с островом — о.

Comment: Точно! С граммами же всё очень серьёзно, без тридцати грамм даже в чувство не придёшь от расстройства, что же творится в мире.